# Is there a generic interface wrapper framework

Tags: c#

Is there a framework or a native way in .net to dynamically generate wrappers for specified interface.  I need a way to say, here is a type I have and here is the interface I want to wrap around it, and for each method it the interface forward calls to these methods on the type provided.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to do this at runtime, [Castle DynamicProxy](http://www.castleproject.org/dynamicproxy/index.html) has a [CreateInterfaceProxyWithoutTarget](http://kozmic.pl/archive/2009/03/20/castle-dynamic-proxy-tutorial-part-viii-interface-proxy-without-target.aspx) API that will do what you're asking.  I believe [LinFu](http://code.google.com/p/linfu/) has something similar.

Answer (score 1):

ReSharper can generate this sort of code for you. Just create a member field or property of the interface type, right-click, use "ReSharper->Code->Generate", then choose "Delegating members".

It will generate members for each of the members of the interface, all of which will delegate through the member property you selected.

Comment: Perfect! And I've been doing this by hand all these years!

Answer (score 1):

With .net 4.0 ImpromptuInterface can do this. It uses the DLR to forward it's method invocation from a proxy generated based on the interface.

impromptu-interface
http://code.google.com/p/impromptu-interface/